# > symbol appearing when interactively defining function in bash

Tags: bash, function, interactive

The behaviour of my shell environment changed:

Earlier, when pasting a function definition e.g.

```
function exampleFunc {
    echo hello
}
```

to the shell, it would display as formatted and register the new function definition.

Now, for some reason, it displays with `>` before each line other than the first.

```
function exampleFunc {
>echo hello
>}
```

I've found that functions containing for loops now fail to be registered.

What might be an explanation for this? How might I revert back to the previous mode?

---

Ubuntu 20.04

This change occurred after installing [nushell](https://www.nushell.sh/), but maybe unrelated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does bash display \`>\` instead of executing my command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/172570)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with you installing `nushell`.  It also does not stop the shell from functioning correctly.

The `>`  is the default value of the shell's *secondary prompt* (`PS2`).  The secondary prompt is displayed whenever the shell requires further input after the user has pressed the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key without completing the current command. This happens only when the shell is in interactive mode.

The POSIX standard [says this about `PS2`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03):

> Each time the user enters a `<newline>` prior to completing a command line in an interactive shell, the value of this variable shall be subjected to parameter expansion and written to standard error. The default value is `>` .

In your specific example, the function definition is the command that still needs to be completed.  It's not until the user enters the closing curly brace, `}`, at the end of the definition that the shell can execute the command.

You will also get the secondary prompt if you are *pasting* in the commands in the `bash` shell if "bracketed paste" has been disabled for the Readline library.  By default, the bracketed paste mode is enabled, meaning the shell will process a pasted chunk of text in one go rather than as individual lines.  This behaviour may be disabled (for future shell sessions) by adding the following line to your `~/.inpturc` file:

```
set enable-bracketed-paste off
```

Bracketed paste mode is also disabled by default if the terminal is "dumb" or if you are using a release of the bash shell older than 5.0.

Different shells may have a different default value in `$PS2`. The `zsh` shell, for example, lets you know what command is currently not complete by dynamically updating the  prompt:

```bash
$ function foo {
function> for arg do
function for>   print -r $arg
function for> done
function> }
$ foo 1 2 3
1
2
3
```

... while the `bash` shell uses a static `>`  string:

```bash
$ function foo {
> for arg do
>   printf '%s\n' "$arg"
> done
> }
$ foo a b c
a
b
c
```

The `nushell` shell seems to use `:::` as its equivalent to the secondary prompt in POSIX-like shells. However, the `nushell` shell does not even attempt to be a POSIX shell.

Unsetting the `PS2` variable in `bash` would potentially lead to confusion. For example, if you think you have just invoked a long-running command but have in fact forgotten a closing quotation mark, you would not have any indication that the shell was waiting for you to complete the command.

Answer (score 0):

The `>` is a *Bourne Shell Variable* known as the *secondary prompt string*.

From gnu.org:

**[Bourne Shell Variable](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Variables)**

> Bash uses certain shell variables in the same way as the Bourne shell.
> In some cases, Bash assigns a default value to the variable.

**[secondary prompt string](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PS2)**, `PS2`

> The secondary prompt string. The default value is ‘> ’. `PS2` is expanded in the same way as PS1 before being displayed.

It can be suppressed using this command:

```
unset PS2
```

Inspired by https://superuser.com/a/1499801/217142

---

I did not work out why my shell introduced `>` as the secondary prompt string. However, as stated by Kusalananda, the problem I had was not to do with that (or installing nushell). Rather, the non-working for loop I mentioned was due to me inadvertently introducing tabs into the editor from which I was copying. This causes bash to [interrupt the function definition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171498/178412) with a `display all X possibilities` message.

To recreate the error, I should have posted:

```
function exampleFunc { 
        echo hello; 
}
```

Note the `\s\t\t` (*space-tab-tab*) before `echo`. When I was simplifying this for the question I failed to recognise the cause. A painful lesson!